# how to retrieve certificate information in C# for client authentication

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-10, tls1.2

I am developing a client application in c# and have created a certificate locally. Now I need to pass on the certificate in streamsocketcontrol object.
For example:

```
socket = new StreamSocket();
Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.Certificate certificate = await GetClientCert();
StreamSocketControl scontrol = socket.Control;
scontrol.ClientCertificate = certificate;
```

and then I am calling:

```
ConnectAsync(hostname, port, tls1.2);
```

I need to understand the implementation of GetClientCert() in C#?

Comment: It looks like `GetClientCert` is in your application code. How are we supposed to know how it's implemented?

Comment: that's the api I need help to implement

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a certificate from one of the certificate stores on your machine, you can do something like the following:

```
var clientCertificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
clientCertificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

var clientCert = clientCertificateStore.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Issuer.Contains("MyIssuerName"));
```

Comment: Thanks James, I dont know why but I'm not able to include system.security.cryptography.x509certificates, under cryptography i couldnt find x509certificates. I'm using visual studio 2015 on windows 10

Comment: Try adding a reference to System.IdentityModel

Comment: You would need to add a reference to the DLL.

Comment: i tried to install through nuget package manager console but got the error that Microsoft.IdentityModel 6.1 not compatible with UAP version=10.0

Comment: by switching on windows identity foundation 3.5 i was able to locate Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll.  I referenced it but even though couldn't able to see x509certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This option is compatible with UWP

```
public async Task<Certificate> GetClientCert()
{ 
    try {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Certificate/clients.pfx"));
        IBuffer certBuffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(sampleFile);
        String encodedCertificate = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(certBuffer);
        Certificate crt = new Certificate(certBuffer);
        return crt;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    return null;
}
```